# Why the database can not be known in Android SQLite?

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I'm making an application Maps connected with SQLite which there are markers, but there is an error that the database can not be recognized, why did it happen? Can anybody help me? This my code :

### MaBase.java

```
public class MaBase  extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    private static final String TABLE_MARK  ="marker.db";
    private static final String COL_ID = "ID";
    private static final String COL_LONG = "LONGITUDE";
    private static final String COL_LAT = "LATITUDE";


    private static final String CREATE_BDD = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_MARK  + " ("
    + COL_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + COL_LONG + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +COL_LAT+" TEXT NOT NULL);";






    public MaBase (Context context, String name, CursorFactory factory, int version) {
        super(context, name, factory, version);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        //on créé la table à partir de la requête écrite dans la variable CREATE_BDD
        db.execSQL(CREATE_BDD);

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE " + TABLE_MARK + ";");
        onCreate(db);
    }

}
```

### MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private static final String NOM_BDD = "marker.db";
    private static final String TABLE_GEOPOINT = "geopoint";
    private static final String COL_ID = "ID";
    private static final String COL_LONG = "LONGITUDE";
    private static final String COL_LAT = "LATITUDE";

    static final LatLng BOGOR = new LatLng(-6.604346, 106.796642);
    private GoogleMap map;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_map);

        sauver_point();  
        map = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map))
                .getMap();

        MaBase maBaseSQLite = new MaBase(MainActivity.this, NOM_BDD, null, 1);
        SQLiteDatabase db = maBaseSQLite.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor c = db.query(TABLE_GEOPOINT, new String[] { COL_ID, COL_LONG,
                COL_LAT }, null, null, null, null, null, null);
        int col = c.getCount(); // col=0 pas de enregistrement qui verifie la
        // condition
        if (col == 0) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Pas de donnees ",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


        } else {
            c.moveToFirst();
            while (c.isAfterLast() == false) {
                // conversion int to string casting
                String id = "" + c.getInt(0);
                String longitude = c.getString(1);
                String latitude = c.getString(2);
                Marker marker = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                .position(
                        new LatLng(Double.parseDouble(latitude),
                                Double.parseDouble(longitude)))
                                .title("Bonjour Tunis")
                                .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
                                        .fromResource(R.drawable.mark2)));
                c.moveToNext();
            }
        }
        c.close();
        db.close();

        map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(BOGOR, 12.0f));

        // Zoom in, animating the camera.
        map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(10), 2000, null);
        map.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    void sauver_point() {
        MaBase maBaseSQLite = new MaBase(MainActivity.this, NOM_BDD, null, 1);
        SQLiteDatabase db = maBaseSQLite.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        // values.put(COL_ID , "1");
        values.put(COL_LAT, "36.830722");
        values.put(COL_LONG, "10.165672");

        db.insert(TABLE_GEOPOINT, null, values);

        // creer un autre utilisateur

        values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(COL_LAT , "36.830922");
        values.put(COL_LONG, "10.275572");
        db.insert(TABLE_GEOPOINT, null, values);

        values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(COL_LAT, "36.930522");
        values.put(COL_LONG, "10.385572");
        db.insert(TABLE_GEOPOINT, null, values);
        values = new ContentValues();

        values.put(COL_LAT, "36.750422");
        values.put(COL_LONG, "10.495572");
        db.insert(TABLE_GEOPOINT, null, values);


        values.put(COL_LAT, "36.936422");
        values.put(COL_LONG, "11.495572");
        db.insert(TABLE_GEOPOINT, null, values);

        values.put(COL_LAT, "36.990422");
        values.put(COL_LONG, "9.995572");
        db.insert(TABLE_GEOPOINT, null, values);

        db.close();

    }

}
```

### LogCat

```
02-12 02:56:00.075: E/SQLiteLog(3453): (1) unknown database marker
02-12 02:56:00.075: D/AndroidRuntime(3453): Shutting down VM
02-12 02:56:00.075: W/dalvikvm(3453): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xa6195908)
02-12 02:56:00.075: E/AndroidRuntime(3453): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-12 02:56:00.075: E/AndroidRuntime(3453): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.bongkorr/com.bongkorr.maps.MainActivity}: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: unknown database marker (code 1): , while compiling: CREATE TABLE marker.db (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, LONGITUDE TEXT NOT NULL, LATITUDE TEXT NOT NULL);
02-12 02:56:00.075: E/AndroidRuntime(3453):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
02-12 02:56:00.075: E/AndroidRuntime(3453):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
02-12 02:56:00.075: E/AndroidRuntime(3453):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
02-12 02:56:00.075: E/AndroidRuntime(3453):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
02-12 02:56:00.075: E/AndroidRuntime(3453):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-12 02:56:00.075: E/AndroidRuntime(3453):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
02-12 02:56:00.075: E/AndroidRuntime(3453):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
02-12 02:56:00.075: E/AndroidRuntime(3453):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-12 02:56:00.075: E/AndroidRuntime(3453):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
02-12 02:56:00.075: E/AndroidRuntime(3453):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
02-12 02:56:00.075: E/AndroidRuntime(3453):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
02-12 02:56:00.075: E/AndroidRuntime(3453):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-12 02:56:00.075: E/AndroidRuntime(3453): Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: unknown database marker (code 1): , while compiling: CREATE TABLE marker.db (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, LONGITUDE TEXT NOT NULL, LATITUDE TEXT NOT NULL);
02-12 02:56:00.075: E/AndroidRuntime(3453):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
02-12 02:56:00.075: E/AndroidRuntime(3453):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:882)
02-12 02:56:00.075: E/AndroidRuntime(3453):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:493)
02-12 02:56:00.075: E/AndroidRuntime(3453):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
02-12 02:56:00.075: E/AndroidRuntime(3453):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
02-12 02:56:00.075: E/AndroidRuntime(3453):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.<init>(SQLiteStatement.java:31)
02-12 02:56:00.075: E/AndroidRuntime(3453):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.executeSql(SQLiteDatabase.java:1663)
02-12 02:56:00.075: E/AndroidRuntime(3453):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.execSQL(SQLiteDatabase.java:1594)
02-12 02:56:00.075: E/AndroidRuntime(3453):     at com.bongkorr.maps.MaBase.onCreate(MaBase.java:31)
02-12 02:56:00.075: E/AndroidRuntime(3453):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getDatabaseLocked(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:252)
02-12 02:56:00.075: E/AndroidRuntime(3453):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:164)
02-12 02:56:00.075: E/AndroidRuntime(3453):     at com.bongkorr.maps.MainActivity.sauver_point(MainActivity.java:86)
02-12 02:56:00.075: E/AndroidRuntime(3453):     at com.bongkorr.maps.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:35)
02-12 02:56:00.075: E/AndroidRuntime(3453):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
02-12 02:56:00.075: E/AndroidRuntime(3453):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
02-12 02:56:00.075: E/AndroidRuntime(3453):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
```

Comment: I don't think you can have a `.` in a table name.

Comment: Your database and your table have the same name, seems like in the "CREATE_BDD" String, what you actually wanted to do is ""CREATE TABLE yourtablename"  + " ("
    + COL_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY..."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Marker.db` should be the name of your database and you should pass it in your constructor. The name of your table should be simply `Marker`:

```
public class MaBase  extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
private static final String DB_MARK  ="marker.db";
private static final String TABLE_MARK  ="marker";
private static final String COL_ID = "ID";
private static final String COL_LONG = "LONGITUDE";
private static final String COL_LAT = "LATITUDE";


private static final String CREATE_BDD = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_MARK  + " ("
+ COL_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + COL_LONG + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +COL_LAT+" TEXT NOT NULL);";






public MaBase (Context context, String name, CursorFactory factory, int version) {
    super(context, DB_MARK, factory, version);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    //on créé la table à partir de la requête écrite dans la variable CREATE_BDD
    db.execSQL(CREATE_BDD);

}
```

...

Comment: Still eror :( @vinitius

Comment: This error **(1) no such table: geopoint, Error inserting LONGITUDE=10.165672 LATITUDE=36.830722,  INSERT INTO geopoint(LONGITUDE,LATITUDE) VALUES (?,?)**

Comment: You're trying to insert in table called `geopoint` now, but I don't see where you created this table

Comment: i created in MainActivity.java @vinitius

Comment: For what I've seen in your code, you should do the insert in `marker`: **INSERT INTO marker(LONGITUDE,LATITUDE) VALUES (?,?)**

Comment: In your `MainActivity` you're trying to save in your table `geopoint` , but you didn't create this table in your database

Comment: so i want to insert markers into the database, then the data is displayed in the maps marker @vinitius

Comment: Ok, so instead of "geopoint" change this in your MainActivity: private static final String TABLE_GEOPOINT = "marker";

Comment: so I save it for the marker is displayed in the maps, but after the database is running, his marker and maps do not appear in my application layout @vinitius

Comment: Oh, I suggest you create a new question to show exactly what's going on :)

Answer (score 1):

`marker.db` as a table name tells to look up a table name `db` in database `marker` and you don't have the database `marker` attached.

Either write the table name in double quotes like `"marker.db"`, or better yet, rename the table to something that better resembles whatever you're putting in there, without a `.`.

Comment: Have error again like this 02-12 03:31:14.092: E/SQLiteDatabase(2375): Error inserting LONGITUDE=10.165672 LATITUDE=36.830722
02-12 03:31:14.092: E/SQLiteDatabase(2375): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: geopoint (code 1): , while compiling: INSERT INTO geopoint(LONGITUDE,LATITUDE) VALUES (?,?)

Comment: Uninstall your app so the old database gets removed and `onCreate()` of the database helper is run again.